# How to implement Android ContentProvider in React Native?

Tags: android, react-native

I need **[ContentProvider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers)** for my **android** application **to share data with other applications**. It seems like *React Native doesn't support it yet*. I checked the official documentation but was unable to find any clue.

In this scenario, I have two options. The first one to check for **any Native Module that offers the support for ContentProvider in React Native**. Again I didn't find any module that can help me.

So the last option I am left with is to build a Native Module for ContentProvider on my own.

Do you have *any idea* about android *ContentProvider support in ReactNative?*

What would you suggest to me in this scenario?